# Why do we sometimes subtract from the exponent in a probability formula?

Tags: probability

I am unsure of why we sometimes subtract from the exponent in a probability formula.

For example, for this question:

A six-sided die is tossed. If it turns up a 1 or 2 the player wins. If it turns up 5 or 6 the player loses. If it turns up 3 or 4 the die is repeatedly tossed until either the same number as the first toss turns up (in which the player wins) or a 5 or 6 turns up in which case the game is lost.

Let $N$ represent the number of tosses until the game stops. Find a formula for $P(N = n)$.

The answer for $n = 1$ is $2/3$, but the answer for n greater or equal $2$ is
$$\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-2}$$

I'm guessing the numbers $1/6$ and $1/2$ are the probabilities for success and failure? I'm also confused about why you need to subtract two from $n$?

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) when writing math :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $n > 1$. How is it possible that $N = n$? We must get a $3$ or $4$ on the first toss (probability $1/3$), then the next $n-2$ tosses can't be $5, 6$, or the first number that was rolled (probability $(1/2)^{n-2}$), then the final toss must be either $5, 6$, or the same as the first toss (probability $1/2$). The probability of this sequence of events occurring is $(1/3) \cdot (1/2)^{n-2} \cdot (1/2)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I still don't get the n - 2 bit, could you explain why you have the n -2 value and how you know to put it on top of the 1/2? And just another thing, how do you know to multiply all these values? Is it from a tree diagram or something?